# How do I call onDraw from a different class?

Tags: android

I created a custom view and added it to my layout in the xml file.  I'm trying to refresh the custom view with a click event but I can't figure out how to call the onDraw method from a different class.  invalidate and postInvalidate aren't refreshing the custom view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create method inside your view which takes the changes and calls invalidate from the inside of your view.

```
public void setTextSize (int size) {
      mTextSize = size; 
      invalidate();
}
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

definitely you should call View.invalidate(). Make sure the view is visible and has measured dimensions - i.e. make sure the view getMeasuerdWidth() and getMeasuerdHeight() return >0.

You put a Log message at the start of your ondraw method to verify it works. but definitely should be invalidate(). Possibly your data isn't changing?

Answer (score 0):

invalidating view results calling of onDraw() method.

by calling customViewClassName.invalidate() from your different class goes to calling of onDraw() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a message handler to achieve such mechanism. In your custom View class, create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), then pass a reference of this handler to the button (for instance in the onCreate event of your Activity), then use the sendMessage() / handleMessage() mechanism to communicate between the Button and the other View.

This method will also allow all the other components to interact nicely with your custom View if you need to.

Comment: What message should I send from my custom view to my activity class? I seemingly can't send an invalidate call or a canvas.